# Removing ALL min and max values and then finding the mean in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, plyr

I have the following dataset:

```
wow <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4), b = c(3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 6, 5), c = c(1, 6, 3, 6, 1, 8, 9))
print(wow)
  a b c
1 1 3 1
2 1 4 6
3 1 2 3
4 2 6 6
5 3 2 1
6 4 6 8
7 4 5 9
```

I need to remove all min and max values from each column, and then calculate the mean of the remaining values so that the result looks like this:

```
print(result)
    a  b    c
1 2.5  4 5.75
```

I found a similar question that was already answered ([mean from row values in a dataframe excluding min and max values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520919/mean-from-row-values-in-a-dataframe-excluding-min-and-max-values-in-r)), but the big difference is that the person asking that question was only dealing with a single min and max value in each column, while I could have multiple min and max values in a column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could remove the values that are `min` and `max` in each column using `%in%`, and get the `mean` from the remaining values.  This can be done either by `summarise_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
summarise_each(wow,funs(mean(.[!.%in% c(min(.), max(.))])))
#    a b    c
#1 2.5 4 5.75
```

Or using `base R`

```
sapply(wow, function(x) mean(x[!x %in% range(x)]))
#   a    b    c 
#2.50 4.00 5.75
```

Answer (score 5):

A `data.table` solution (`1.9.5+`, but can easily be back-fit) to return a `data.frame`-like object, which it seems you wanted:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(wow)[,lapply(.SD,function(x)mean(x[x>min(x)&x<max(x)]))]
```

or, *a la* @akrun

```
setDT(wow)[,lapply(.SD,function(x)mean(x[!x%in%range(x)]))]
```

You may need an `na.rm=T` depending on your data; there should also be a way to do this with `.GRP` but I think it's going to end up being longer than the above.

If you want `result` to be a vector, use `sapply` (in which case the `data.frame` solution is basically identical, and the only advantage of `data.table` is speed).