# Calculate mean of row excluding the highest and lowest value in each row

Tags: r

I have a data frame with ~32k rows and 36 columns. I am trying to calculate the `mean` of each row and creating a separate `column` containing the `mean` for each row. I originally calculated it for `columns 19:33` via `data$mean <- data[,19:33]` however now I want to exclude the highest and lowest values in each row to calculate the mean. Each row will have different high and low values in different locations. How can I effectively calculate the mean for each row while excluding those two values in each row?

Comment: `apply(X = data[,19:33], MARGIN = 1, function(x) mean(replace(x, c(which.min(x), which.max(x)), NA), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mean from row values in a dataframe excluding min and max values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520919/mean-from-row-values-in-a-dataframe-excluding-min-and-max-values-in-r)

Comment: awesome! worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: My answer worked ?

Comment: I used db's and it worked fine, I did not use yours wen

Comment: Ok depends on you

Answer (score 2):

Try using `apply`, `%in%`,`range`

```
apply(df[,19:33], 1, function(x) mean(x[!x %in% range(x)]))
```